# Git is installed but .git directory is absent so i can;t configure it

Tags: git, ubuntu, root

`.git` folder does not exist

Last month same configuration had the .git directory

```
ls -la
total 97
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Apr 19 09:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Apr 19 09:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 16 05:01 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  1024 Apr 16 05:03 boot
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  3980 May 15 03:42 dev
drwxr-xr-x  92 root root  4096 May 17 02:58 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 16 05:03 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Apr 16 04:57 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Apr 16 05:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 16 04:57 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Apr 16 04:57 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr 16 04:57 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  1  2017 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  1  2017 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 186 root root     0 May 15 03:42 proc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 19 09:22 pub
drwx------   3 root root  4096 May 17 04:39 root
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root   920 May 17 02:58 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Apr 16 05:03 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 29  2017 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  1  2017 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 May 17 02:59 sys
drwxrwxrwt   9 root root  4096 May 17 05:39 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Apr 16 04:57 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Apr 16 05:02 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Apr 16 04:57 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic
```

Can't create folder

Comment: Are you talking about `.gitconfig`? What does `git config --list --show-origin` return? If you're talking about `.git`, then it's a project specific folder.

Comment: The `.git` directory is unique for a project, try to `git clone` any project from `github` and you will see `.git` there

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the `.gitconfig` file, then it should be located under your home directory. This file contains user-specific configuration.

The `.git` folder is created inside the repository when you run `git init`. It contains all the information that is needed for the version control for your project. It also contains information about commits, remote repos, addresses and more.

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

> This command creates an empty Git repository - basically a `.git` directory with subdirectories for `objects`, `refs/heads`, `refs/tags`, and template files. An initial `HEAD` file that references the HEAD of the master branch is also created.